# ScripDuplicating directory structure !

Tags: linux, bash, script

I have a following directory structure for my code 
containing *.c ad *.h files and some configuration
and build files generated by automake & autoconf 
I want to copy only the *.c and *.h files into new directory 
structure like this

```
testdir/
├── subtest1
│   └── subtest11
│       ├── test111.c
│       └── test111.h
└── subtest2
    └── test.c

newtestdir/ <--------------------- ONLY THIS DIRECTORY IS CHANGED !!
├── subtest1
│   └── subtest11
│       ├── test111.c
│       └── test111.h
└── subtest2
    └── test.c
```

Any hints as to how to do this on Linux ???

Thanks for the gr8 work of sharing knowledge !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rsync -a -f"+ */" -f"+ *.[hc]" -f"- *" testdir newtestdir
```

Answer (score 0):

`rsync` with use of `--include` can do this.